# SwiftUI webview not updating with @State variable

Tags: swift, swiftui, wkwebview

For some reason the @State variable that I am using to update the url of my WebView is not updating. Both buttons result in the 'www.target.com' url.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var siteArray = ["http://www.google.com","http://www.yahoo.com","http://www.amazon.com"]
    @State private var siteUrl = "http://www.target.com"
    @State private var showWebView = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView{
            Text("Websites")
            Button("Target") {
                showWebView.toggle()
            }
            Button("Google") {
                siteUrl = siteArray[0]
                showWebView.toggle()
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showWebView) {
                                                
        WebView(url: URL(string: "\(siteUrl)")!)
                                            }
}
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: try using the `.sheet(item: ...)` version of sheet instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use @Binding
for exemple:

```
struct WebView: View {
@Binding var siteUrl :String
var body: some View {
    Text(siteUrl)
}
}

struct ContentView: View {
var siteArray =    ["http://www.google.com","http://www.yahoo.com","http://www.amazon.com"]
@State private var siteUrl = "http://www.target.com"
@State private var showWebView = false

var body: some View {
    ScrollView{
        Text("Websites")
        Button("Target") {
            showWebView.toggle()
        }
        Button("Google") {
            siteUrl = siteArray[1]
            showWebView.toggle()
        }
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $showWebView) {
        WebView(siteUrl: $siteUrl)
        
    }
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks!